# 90s TV show about paranormal cases with host with a ponytail

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, horror, mystery

I remember a TV show from around 97 or 98 about paranormal stories, though it didn't last long in the USA since in my country it lasted for like 10 episodes but I might be wrong.

The show followed a dynamic where the host would present two stories per episode, and the stories would be reenacted by other actors with no narration from the host.

The host was a very muscular white man, sporting always a black t-shirt and dark blue jeans and had his hair tied up in a ponytail.

One of the stories I remember the most was about a woman who thought someone was living in her apartment only to be revealed she was the intruder suffering from mental illness.

I don't know if this show lasted longer on the USA, I watched it around 97 or 98, but it might had come out earlier but no earlier than 95.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds very much like [Night Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Visions_(TV_series)), with a couple of exceptions.

**Similarities:**

- Short lived (13 episode) early '00s show where each episode contained 2 paranormal stories;
- The host was [Henry Rollins](http://theworldbyroad.com/collective/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tumblr_m4ya4xS3zH1qazb99o1_1280.jpg), a muscular guy who always wears a tight black shirt;
- The episode you're describing sounds exactly like a story in episode 6 (called *The Occupant* with [Bridget Fonda](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzMzk5OTQzNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc0OTk0._V1_UX214_CR0,0,214,317_AL_.jpg)).

**Exceptions:**

- The year is a bit off;
- Henry Rollins with a ponytail? I don't think so... Maybe when he was in his teens, but not *then*.

Here's the intro:

Comment: The year and hair were wrong on my part, that's the tv show, I had forgotten it was Henry Rollins the one hosting, I had the impression of a ponytail but that's him indeed